# SQL how to make query with CROSS JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to make one query with cross join. I have been trying it for 1 hour, but I still don't get what I need. I am trying to make this query: Show pilots who were flying on every aircraft of manufacturer CESSNA. For this query I need two entities: PILOT and FLIGHT.
In PILOT I have these atributes:

1. PILOT_ID
2. Name
3. Street
4. City
5. Country

In FLIGHT there are these atributes:

1. PILOT_ID (from pilot table)
2. ID_FLIGHT
3. departure airport
4. destination airport
5. duration of flight
6. ID_AIRCRAFT
7. name of aircraft manufacturer

I was trying to make it WITH T1 as... T2 as... by "temp" tables but with bad result. And of course there have to be a cross join. Could anybody help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For that kind of query you will need an `inner join` (or possibly a `left join`) not a `cross join`.

Comment: Can you show what query you tried and why it didn't work?   It would help to understand the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help get you started?

```
 select pilots.*
from pilots 
    inner join flights on pilots.pilot_id = flights.pilot_id
where flights.[nameofaircraft] = 'CESSNA'
```